# Rows and columns in 2D array

Tags: php

I have a 2D array with unknown number of element.

`$two_darray[row][column]; //there will be an unknown integer values instead of row and column keywords`

If I were to write a `for` loop as follows, how can I determine how many rows and columns in my `$two_darray`. Can you please tell me if there is a library function in php that can tell me the value inside [????] [????]

```
for($row=0; $row<………; $row++)
{
    for($column =0; $column  <………; $ column ++)
    {
        echo $two_darray[$row][$column];
    }
    echo “\n end of one column \n”;
}
```

I really need to know the value of rows and columns in order to perform other calculations

Comment: Why do you need the row and column count? what do you want to achieve, if i knew maybe i could help you beyond this particular problem. Maybe there are alternative solutions you have not thought of etc...